# Input string was not in a correct format, error coming

Tags: c#, asp.net

I m getting error:

> input string was not in corect format

in the line:

```
int amount = Convert.ToInt32(txtAmount.Text);
```

Comment: Simply, `txtAmount.Text` is not a number.

Comment: What is the value of `txtAmount.Text` exactly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to make sure that you type only numerics in your TextBox, e.g. 1 2 3 .

In case you type any non numeric characters likes alphabets etc.. then it won't be convertible to an equivalent Integer. for example string: `"234"` can be converted to integer but `"23A4"` cannot.

Below are 3 methods for conversion to integer:

`Int32.Parse()`, `Convert.ToInt32()`, and `Int32.TryParse()`

Of these 3 `Int32.TryParse()` doesn't throws exception on error. Instead it returns `0` on any error encountered in conversion.

```
Int32.TryParse(string s, out int) 
When s is a null reference, it will return 0 rather than throw 
ArgumentNullException. If s is other than an integer value, the out 
variable will have 0 rather than FormatException. When s represents
a number less than MinValue or greater than MaxValue, the out variable 
will have 0 rather than OverflowException
```

Check ***[this link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32885/Difference-Between-Int32-Parse-Convert-ToInt32-and)*** for a complete understanding on these 3 methods.